# converting const char to string isn't working

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, std, const-char

Trying to convert type `const char` to type `std::string`. All the examples I've seen are for `const char *`. If I change my type to * the `dc.at` will fail.

The conversion to string is failing. I've been trawling for an hour, it can't be that hard, I'm clearly missing something simple.

```
std::string dc = "fdsda4w4bfd*4t4vwrsv";
const char dcchar = dc.at(11);
std::string ms_char = dcchar;
```

[image]

`std::string ms_char(dchar);` also fails

Comment: Do you get an error? If so what is the exact text of the error message?

Comment: Note: when you get a compiler error, you can copy-paste it into google and most likely find a solution.

Comment: *I'm clearly missing something simple.* -- What you're missing is calling the correct version of the `std::string` constructor that takes a char and a count.

Comment: Thanks guys, duplicate link above worked a charm